# Can't identify a popup in Oracle-APEX using Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, oracle-apex

We're building an application using Oracle Apex and I've been tasked with writing automated tests in Selenium WebDriver.

This application often causes a popup to occur, but I have been unable to interact with the popup - I get the typical unable to locate element message.

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/button")).click(); // show popup


    String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
    String subWindowHandler = null;

    //move to popup.
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
                                                // perform operations on popup

    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl())

    driver.findElement(By.id("P15_NAME")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("P15_NAME")).sendKeys("Test");
    driver.findElement(By.id("P15_DESCRIPTION")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("P15_DESCRIPTION")).sendKeys("Test");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div/button")).click(); // 'Create' button, closes popup.
```

The getWindowHandles() and iterator code was from another popup suggestion, but I believe that something may be different here as the site is coded in APEX.
I was executing the code against Firefox 41.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say popup... what does that mean? Is it an HTML dialog or a true browser window? getWindowHandles() is only for additional browser instances.

Comment: If you're talking apex 5: it has become a lot easier to define modal dialogs and likely it's being used a lot. If still on apex 4, then it's maybe a modal dialog plugin. Either way, it's as JeffC says: these dialogs are modal dialogs, ie iframes, and not true browser windows.

Comment: Yeah this is apex 5, but I've learned it's being done via a plugin. I'll look into iframes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframe's were the key here.
where using

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
```

was how to interact with the frame.

then I returned to the base frame via

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```